# How can I perform swipe left "with particular coordinate or height of screen" in XCUI test?

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest

```
app.swipeLeft()
```

I'm using this `swipeLeft` function but it swipes at the middle of the page but I want to perform a swipe gesture at the top of the page. Is there any way I can give a coordinate or like a page top as a parameter while performing the swipe left function?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom func and use app.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)) to specify the top-left corner as the starting point. example...

func swipeLeft() {
let app = XCUIApplication()

```
    // Set coordinates for the top-left 
    let startCoordinate = app.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.1, dy: 0.1))

    let endCoordinate = app.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 0.1))


    startCoordinate.press(forDuration: 0.1, thenDragTo: endCoordinate)

   
}
```